# Error System.TypeInitializationException while debugging

Tags: c#

I got following error when I process the code that I got from my friend, would you think it is an environment setup problem?

Error message appears at: `com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getInstance(Document document, Stream os)`

Error message:

```
System.TypeInitializationException occurred
HResult=-2146233036
Message=The type initializer for 'com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter' threw an exception.
Source=iTextdotNET
TypeName=com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter
StackTrace:
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getInstance(Document document, Stream os)
    at ABCSystem.PDFCreator.Create() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ABCSystem\PDFCreator.cs:line 103
InnerException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
    HResult=-2146233088
    Message=Exception of type 'java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError' was thrown.
    Source=vjslib
    StackTrace:
        at
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.checkAndThrowException(Throwable thrown)
        at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter..cctor()
   InnerException:
```

Actual Code:

```
System.TypeInitializationException occurred
HResult=-2146233036
Message=The type initializer for '' threw an exception.
Source=iTextdotNET
TypeName=com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter
StackTrace:
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getInstance(Document document, Stream os) <------------- this is where the code stopped
    at ABCSystem.PDFCreator.Create() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ABCSystem\PDFCreator.cs:line 103
InnerException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
    HResult=-2146233088
    Message=Exception of type 'java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError' was thrown.
    Source=vjslib
    StackTrace:
        at java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.checkAndThrowException(Throwable thrown)
        at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter..cctor()
    InnerException:
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: `TypeInitializationException` means that the type *static constructor* throws an exception.

Comment: Indeed. Of an assembly not under his project. Maybe it is documented what to do in this situation. Do you have all required assemblies and java packages?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thank you very much for the quick reply! Would you think you can find out what is mission? i have uploaded a screenshot of the message.

Comment: I guess some java components are missing from your project location, but I have no experience with this package. Check their documentation if you followed all steps.

Comment: Does anybody find the answer for this problem? I have this problem too.